# webix reset yAxis and reload data but the display is wrong

Tags: charts, reload, webix

I'have the following code which has a problem.

```
//reset the yAxis with new value
$$("chartStock1").yAxis_setter({ start:lowestValue, step:stepValue, end:highestValue, template:function(value){ return value } }); 

//clear data
$$("chartStock1").clearAll()

//reload data
$$("chartStock1").parse(jiugangArray);
```

I'd like to reset the `yAxis` of the line chart and the values seems OK. Then I reload the data by the 'parse' function and the data in the array is also OK.

The line chart was drawn due to the older `yAxis`, but not due to the brand-new `yAxis` value. This is quite confusing.

Answer (score 0):

It is more correct to use define() method instead of setter:

```
$("chartStock1").define("yAxis",{ 
 start:lowestValue, 
 step:stepValue, 
 end:highestValue, 
 template:function(value){ return value } 
});
```